# arctan(x) function in python

Tags: python, function, trigonometry

The Write a function that will return an approximate value for pi by evaluating the equation  pi = arctan(1/5) - arctan(1/239), where arctan is the tangent function from the math library . Im using python 3.4.1

The function I used was:

```
def wallis(pairs):
    acc = 1
    num = 2
    for apair in range(pairs):
        leftterm = math.atan(0.2)
        rightterm = math.atan(0.0041)

        acc = leftterm - rightterm

        return pi
```

but it didn't work. It's confusing.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "but it didn't work"... what's expected, what have you already got etc...? - also where is `pi` ever defined in that function...

Comment: You don't calculate pi anywhere.  You say "return pi" but you never have an expression like "pi = ..." so it's not a variable.

Comment: @AdamHughes since the OP hasn't included the *exact* error or suitable traceback - it's (unlikely) plausible it does exist in a global scope... but that's here-say and without further information, not possible to conclude :)

Comment: @Cb173 If you'd to use the `math` library for computation of pi, why not simple use `math.pi` for the value of pi.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you got that formula;

it looks like you were trying to do Wallis' formula, `pi = (2/1) * (2/3) * (4/3) * (4/5) * ...` and switched mid-stream to Machin's formula, `pi == 16 * atan(1/5) - 4 * atan(1/239)`.

```
from math import atan

def approx_pi():
    return 16 * atan(1/5) - 4 * atan(1/239)
```

then

```
>>> approx_pi()
3.1415926535897936
```

Comment: See the thing is I did the exact same thing you did but I import the math library wrong. I got the formula from my python textbook. It was the Wallis formula.

Comment: @CassandraBrown: the "exact same"? _Really?_ I count six crucial errors _not_ involving how you imported `atan`... and this _isn't_ Wallis' formula.